# how to send collection of Data from window appliaction using web API

Tags: c#

I need help,
how to send a collection of data using web API in C# window application.

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AcceptVerbs("POST")]
    public void Inventory(long TenantId, [FromBody] string JsonInventory)
    {
        try
        {
            List<Inventory> lstInventory = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Inventory>>(JsonInventory);
            foreach (var item in lstInventory)
            {

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

my web API method,
now I want to call this method via my desktop application

```
                    string str = Inventory();
                    using (WebClient httpclient = new WebClient())
                    {

                        string url = "http://localhost:51411/api/MobileAPI/Inventory?TenantId=" + CommonClass.tenantId + "&JsonInventory=" + str;

                        //string url = "http://localhost:51411/api/MobileAPI/Inventory?JsonInventory='abc'";
                        //string url = "http://localhost:51411/";
                        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
                        var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
                        {
                         new KeyValuePair<string, string>("", str)
                         });
```

}

Comment: You need to send a string content.

Comment: here is my Inventory model 
public class Inventory
    {
        public string ItemId { get; set; }
        public string Category { get; set; }
        public decimal Price1 { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public int QuantityAvailable { get; set; }
        public int QuantityOnHand { get; set; }
        public string Method { get; set; }
    }

Comment: I am not getting how to send can you give me some solution with code after reading my code

Comment: Did you convert your object allready into json?

Comment: string str = Inventory();
this function will return data in json format, now i need to send this data in my web URL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks guys, I got solution now

```
                    string str = Inventory();
                    using (WebClient httpclient = new WebClient())
                    {
                        //string str = "abc";
                        string url = "http://localhost:51411/api/MobileAPI/Inventory?TenantId=" + CommonClass.tenantId;

                        ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
                        byte[] data = encoding.GetBytes(str);

                        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
                        request.Method = "Post";
                        request.ContentLength = data.Length;
                        request.ContentType = "application/json";

                        using (Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream())
                        {
                            stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
                        }

                        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
                    }
```

my web API Method is like this

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AcceptVerbs("POST")]
    async public Task Inventory(long TenantId)
    {
        try
        {
            byte[] data = await Request.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
            string JsonInventory = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(data);
            List<Inventory> lstInventory = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Inventory>>(JsonInventory);
            foreach (var item in lstInventory)
            {

            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Typicly when sending json to a web api you need to send the json as request body. You can do this with the `HttpClient` and `StringContent` class.

```
public async Task PostInventory(string jsonInventory, int tenantId)
{
    var url = "http://localhost:51411/api/MobileAPI/Inventory?TenantId=" + tenantId;
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, url);
        request.Content = new StringContent(jsonInventory, Encoding.UTF8, "text/plain");
        await client.SendAsync(request);
    }
}
```

Comment: it doesn't work for me, can my break point hit? in web?
I just call await PostInventory(str, CommonClass.tenantId);
but break point in web post method did not hit

Comment: @MohanChandra is any exception thrown or what status code are you getting in the response?

Comment: by your code i am not getting anything, but it doesn't work, i think i am missing something, i am implemeting this service first time, already sync method is going by wcf but now we want via web api for faster

Comment: @MohanChandra change the last line to `var response = await client.SendAsync(request);` and look at the `response.StatusCode` property.

Comment: StatusCode: 415, ReasonPhrase: 'Unsupported Media Type'

url value is http://localhost:51411/api/MobileAPI/Inventory?TenantId=-8372003342106636707

Comment: @MohanChandra I've updated my answer so you can upload your content as string. Note that in generell you shouldn't convert the json on the server side by yourself. The content formaters usually take care of this.

Comment: Misused header name. Make sure request headers are used with HttpRequestMessage, response headers with HttpResponseMessage, and content headers with HttpContent objects.

Comment: @MohanChandra syr compleatly forgot that. This should work

Comment: no problem, thanks for your valuable time, but 
[HttpPost]
        [AcceptVerbs("POST")]
        public void Inventory(long TenantId, string JsonInventory)

string url = "http://localhost:51411/api/MobileAPI/Inventory?TenantId=" + CommonClass.tenantId + "&JsonInventory=" + str;

this only i am able to hit my break point in web API but instead of a single string i needed a collection

Comment: @MohanChandra You should only send simple types as int, long usw as query string parameter. The json string is now send in the request body. And therefore you don't need the second query string parameter in the url.

Comment: using (WebClient httpclient = new WebClient())
            {
                string str = "abc";
                string url = "http://localhost:51411/api/MobileAPI/Inventory?TenantId=" + CommonClass.tenantId + "&JsonInventory=" + str;

                HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
                request.Method = "Post";
                request.ContentLength = 0;
                HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            }

by this i am able to hit my break point

Comment: web api change by 

 [HttpPost]
        [AcceptVerbs("POST")]
        public void Inventory(long TenantId, string JsonInventory)
        {
            try
            {
                List<Inventory> lstInventory = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Inventory>>(JsonInventory);
                foreach (var item in lstInventory)
                {

                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
    }

Comment: @MohanChandra by this you aren't sending your json as request body but in the query string. Be carefull with that as there is a limit of information which can be transmitted and you have to base64 endode your json that you don't send invalid characters

Answer (score 1):

First of all - I don't recommend you to use json string as parameter of web api method. You are restricting your api to single content type and you losing the power of parameter binding (you have to deserialize json manually). So, first step will be changing your API

```
[Route("inventory")]
public IHttpActionResult PostInventories(long TenantId, 
   [FromBody] List<Inventory> inventories) // parameter will be deserialized automatically
{
    foreach (var item in inventories)
    {
        //...
    }

    // catching and rethrowing exception is redundant as well
    return Ok();
}
```

Note that I also change return type of method to `IHttpActionResult`. And changed method name to `PostInventories` in order to use the convention which maps methods names to HTTP verbs.

Next - the client. It's easy to query API with `HttpClient` class:

```
var client = new HttpClient(); 
client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:51411/api");
var json = Inventory();

// NOTE: your Inventory() method should do something similar following lines   
// var inventories = new []{ new Inventory(1, "foo"), new Inventory(2, "bar") };
// var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(inventories);

var content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
var response = await client.PostAsync("mobileAPI/inventory?tenantId=42", content);
```

Or even better - add nuget package *Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client* - it contains *System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll* with extension methods for `HttpClient` which will do content creation and serialization for you:

```
var client = new HttpClient(); 
client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:51411/api");
var inventories = new []{ new Inventory(1, "foo"), new Inventory(2, "bar") };
var response =await client.PostAsJsonAsync("mobileAPI/inventory?tenantId=42", inventories);
```

Comment: StatusCode: 404, ReasonPhrase: 'Not Found', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent,

one thing i wanna call this url via my desktop application to web application.

Comment: @MohanChandra that means web api wan't able to match request to any route. Probably you are missing attribute routing configuration in your web api application. You should add `httpConfig.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();` just before you map default http route.

Comment: in web.config we need to be some changes or in desktop App.config file?

Comment: @MohanChandra it's not config. its server settings where you define routes